# Error using partial view, javascript and viewbag foreach

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, viewbag

I'm trying to load a partial view using JavaScript, in turn the partial view will have a View Bag", to loop through.
All is working well, until I try to render the partial view I get an "**object Object**" error, if I remove the View bag loop the partial view loads

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ServiceDetails(int id )
        {
            int count = 0;

           var m = from c in db.ServiceCategoryFields
                    where c.serviceTypeID == id
                    select c;
            ViewBag.count  = count;
            ViewBag.m = m.ToList();
            return PartialView(m.ToList());
        }
```

**Partial View**

```
<table style ="width:100% ">
     <tr>
     @foreach (var image in (List<String>)ViewBag.m)
    {
        <td>
           @image
        </td>
     }  

  </tr>
```

**JS File**

```
type: "POST",
            success: function (data) {

                display.html('');
                display.html(data);
            },
            error: function (reponse) {
                alert("JS Error : " + reponse.toString());
            }
```

Comment: Does your partial view have a model?

Comment: What does the display contains ? It should be the div that contain the partialview. Something like this : var display = $("MySelector"). Setup before the ajax call.

Comment: What response do you get before rendering it with `display.html(data);`?

Comment: might be because there's a cast error? does the LINQ query returns a list of strings or a list of complex objects? I'd suggest also to  use OR the model OR the viewbag, not both.

Comment: What does `ServiceCategoryField` class look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Quick Solution

Based on your controller code below

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ServiceDetails(int id )
{
    int count = 0;

    var m = from c in db.ServiceCategoryFields
            where c.serviceTypeID == id
            select c;
    ViewBag.count  = count;
    ViewBag.m = m.ToList();
    return PartialView(m.ToList());
}
```

`ViewBag.m` would be an instance of `List<ServiceCategoryField>`, but you convert it to `List<string>` in the partial view

```
@foreach (var image in (List<String>)ViewBag.m)
```

so you got the error. Assuming that `PropertyName` is the property of `ServiceCategoryField` with the value that you want to display inside `<td>` tags, you need to convert `ViewBag.m` to `List<ServiceCategoryField>` in the partial view as below

```
<table style ="width:100% ">
    <tr>
    @foreach (var image in (List<ServiceCategoryField>)ViewBag.m)
    {
        <td>
           @image.PropertyName
        </td>
    }  

  </tr>
```

### Alternative Solution

The previous solution requires converting `ViewBag.m` and it could produce runtime errors if you convert `ViewBag.m` to the wrong type. You can avoid the conversion in the partial view by using this alternative solution.

The first thing to do is creating a model class that will be used by the partial view, let's say the class name is `ServiceDetailsViewModel` and it has `Count` and `Images` property

```
public class ServiceDetailsViewModel
{
    public int Count { get; set; }
    public List<string> Images { get; set; }
}
```

Create an instance of `ServiceDetailsViewModel`, assign the properties, and pass `model` to the partial view in the controller. I assume `PropertyName` is a string and `c.PropertyName` is where the `image` in the partial view comes from

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ServiceDetails(int id )
{
    int count = 0;

    var m = from c in db.ServiceCategoryFields
            where c.serviceTypeID == id
            select c.PropertyName;

    ServiceDetailsViewModel model = new ServiceDetailsViewModel();
    model.Count  = count;
    model.Images = m.ToList();

    return PartialView(model);
}
```

Set `ServiceDetailsViewModel` as the model by using the below syntax at the top of your partial view code

```
@model ServiceDetailsViewModel
```

and loop through `Model.Images` as below

```
<table style ="width:100% ">
    <tr>
    @foreach (var image in Model.Images)
    {
        <td>
           @image
        </td>
    }  
    </tr>
```